# How to properly arrange the elements around table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help with css for table and buttons.
I have a  [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltTyg.png)

And now I have this: [my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOGEX.png)

Bellow are my html and css

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #00A1D4;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.plus_button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFBA5C;
  border: none;
  background-image: url("plus.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.minus_button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #881013;
  border: none;
  background-image: url("minus.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <button onclick="appendCol()" class="plus_button"></button>
  <button onclick="deleteRow()" class="minus_button"></button>
  <button onclick="appendRow()" class="plus_button"></button>
  <button onclick="deleteCol()" class="minus_button"></button>
```

Note: table is dynamic and during clicking plus and minus button I can add rows and columns but table always should be located in the center.

I tied float and display, position. Result always - table moved to left

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could put the table and buttons in one container together that is centered and has `position: relative;`. The bottom button could then have `position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: -80px;` and the right button could have `position: absolute; top: 0; right: -80px;`.

Comment: [JSfiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/q3wfv66x/)

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful. Buttons now in right position.
Can you show in you example how to make horizontal center for this container. Because it was moved to left and I do not know how to do it.

Comment: To horizontally align, try `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` in the parent div of `table`

Comment: Thank you! I Try to add `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` to body and now it is how I want.